# SQL Server : Transactional Replication Filter By Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

There is a database that contains records for multiple groups of people. These records do not contain a column indicating which group the record is "owned" by (very frustrating). I need to setup transactional replication to each different group, which would contain only the records that they own.

It would be possible to create a computed column which would contain the logic to derive who the owning group is (note that in some cases, this computed column would have to call a scalar function because the logic may have to join tables to determine the owner).

I am wondering if it is possible to setup a row filter on the computed column for use in transaction replication. Would it matter whether the computed column was persistent or not?

Note that using indexed views is of course an option; however, this would double the space requirements of the database.

Comment: I ran a test with just a basic computed column and it worked. You'll want to set up a test that parallels your exact scenario.